# Tibco process gets stuck at JDBC query activity intermittently, How to indentify what is the issue?

Tags: jdbc, tibco-business-works, hung, tibco-topic, tibco-designer

Tibco process instance is getting hung/Stuck at particular JDBC query activity every now and then, After restart of Tibco interface from admin,it works fine.
This is an intermittent issue.
anyone has idea, what could be the problem?

==> Tried connecting DB directly from SQL developer while the process was stuck in Tibco, it worked fine from SQL developer. So assuming it should not be a connection issue.

==> The process is not even getting timeout, sometime it gets stuck till few days before we realize.

Please let me know if you need more details on this issue
Thanks in advance

Comment: You may activate the 10046 trace in the connection,  to see what is the problem.

Comment: Could you please provide jdbc connection configuration screen? what jdbc driver is used? we had similar issue with DB2 jt400.jar driver when database sending some message (like password expiration notice etc) during connection initialization.